# Detect movement of two phones in an area?

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, gps, geolocation

A mobile app I'm designing with Ionic requires that I (backend) or another user (phone 1) am able to detect movement of another user (phone 2).

Usage scenario:

1. I want to set a landmark/beacon (latitude + longitude) at my current location, and log these coordinates.
2. Once I leave my current position ( position of the landmark ), I want to be able to confirm when a specific user moves to my landmark.

It'd require an accuracy / granularity of about 10 feet.
I've already looked at things like
[p2pkit.io](http://p2pkit.io/) and [ngGeolocation](https://github.com/ninjatronic/ngGeolocation), but neither seem accurate enough. Battery life is not a concern, as this particular part of the app will be used very briefly.

Any and all help or insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- ngGeolocation has an options parameter (the third one), where you can set "enableHighAccuracy" to true. This is very accurate, depends on your device.
- For background geo location, I can recommend [cordova-background-geolocation-services](https://github.com/pmwisdom/cordova-background-geolocation-services) by pmwisdom (link to GitHub). It makes geolocation work in the background, and has some more neat features for battery efficiency (e.g. geolocation won't be sent if device hasn't moved X feet). Also since you're using android, this specific background addon does not require any payment (unlike others out there).